# List of items in a folder using sub string of filename

Tags: powershell

I have a directory which contains .xls files named as follows:

**Recon_[Account No]_[YYYYMMDD].xls**

e.g:

**Recon_9020111006076954416_20131216.xls**

The Account number can be any number of characters between 16 and 20.

I need to get a list of items in this folder - but only the account numbers.

What would be FANTASTIC is if I could get a list of account numbers and then next to them the date the file was created (which can be the datestamp in the file name or the last modified date of the file), in YYYY/MM/DD format, sorted by date.

Like this:

9020111006076954416    2013/12/16
10201129080000235952   2013/12/17

I then need this list of accounts in a text file, or even better, an excel file. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Fairly, easy, actually:

1. First obtain the raw data

   ```
   Get-ChildItem *.xls |
   ```
2. Then extract the properties you need from it:

   ```
   ForEach-Object {
       if ($_.Basename -match '^Recon_(?<account>\d+)_(?<date>\d+)$') {
           $_ | Add-Member NoteProperty AccountNumber $Matches.account
       }
   } |
   ```
3. Select those properties you are interested in (we are still dealing with the original `FileInfo` object, we just added the account number to it):

   ```
   Select-Object AccountNumber,LastWriteTime
   ```

   You could make the header nicer as well:

   ```
   Select-Object @{l='Account Number'; e={$_.AccountNumber}}, @{l='Date'; e={$_.LastWriteTime}}
   ```

At this point you have something you can display on screen nicely. You can then continue formatting the data by piping it into another `ForEach-Object`:

```
ForEach-Object {
    '{0}`t{1:yyyy-MM-dd}' -f $_.AccountNumber, $_.LastWriteTime
}
```

or convert it to CSV (which Excel can then open) by piping into `ConvertTo-Csv`:

```
ConvertTo-Csv foo.csv
```

To recap:

```
$data = Get-ChildItem *.xls |
          ForEach-Object {
              if ($_.Basename -match '^Recon_(?<account>\d+)_(?<date>\d+)$') {
                  $_ | Add-Member NoteProperty AccountNumber $Matches.account
              }
          } |
          Select-Object AccountNumber,LastWriteTime

$data | ForEach-Object {
    "{0}`t{1:yyyy-MM-dd}" -f $_.AccountNumber, $_.LastWriteTime
} | Out-File foo.txt

$data | ConvertTo-Csv foo.csv
```

Comment: The txt file doesn't return the Account Numbers, and has records like this:   `t2013-12-03

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.xls | Where-Object {$_.BaseName -match '^Recon_\d{16,20}_\d+$'} | ForEach-Object{

    $id,$date = $_.BaseName.Split('_')[1..2]

    New-Object PSObject -Property @{
       AccountNumber = $id
       DateCreated = $date.Insert(4,'/').Insert(7,'/')
    }

} | Export-Csv itemList.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Hi, this almost works, except that the account number needs to be in text format as excel will convert it to something like 10201106070000100000 - also, how can I sort by date?

Comment: All values are text. Do you want the date to be a datetime object (rather than a string)?

Answer (score 0):

Get all files of this directory. in a loop get file name and split it by '_'. the second item of array is account number and the third one is date.